# Batch several remoting calls within a single transaction on server-side

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, remoting

I am looking the way to batch several remote calls from flex-based application to java-based server, so that they would be processed within a single transaction on the server-side.

My idea is to build several services on server-side with setter/getter like operations:

```
interface MyService1 {
  void setField1(long myEntity1Id, int field1Value);
  void setField2(long myEntity1Id, int field2Value);
  ...
}
interface MyService2 {
  void setField1(long myEntity2Id, int field1Value);
  void setField2(long myEntity2Id, int field2Value);
  ...
}
```

Calling such method independently, each in a separate transaction has no meaning, each of them just changes some field, so that some setter fails in the middle of that batch, rolling back all previous is required.

Are there any way to do this?
Can I manually assign several asynchronous calls to a single HTTP request on flex-side and make that request establish a single transaction on server-side?

Are there any frameworks/libraries for this or standard functionality?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Swiz framework provides a nice [Chaining API](http://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Chaining+API). I like it because you can use the chaining functionality without committing to the entire framework architecture. Although, it is decent framework all around. We use it in all our projects. :)